# Can I connect a cord and a GFCI outlet box to another GFCI outlet to power a pump?

Tags: pool, pump

I have a gfi receptacle I am plugging a drop cord
Into it and running it to a box with a switch and gfi receptacle in it.
I am plugging a pump into this gfi.
Will this work

Comment: Why are you adding an extra GFCI to this picture?

Answer (score 2):

It might work but would not be code compliant and with 2 GFCI’s on the same circuit you may have nuisance tripping. If you test the GFCI at the box it may trip that one and the one inside.